# Cronjob working every 5 minutes, but not at a given specific time

Tags: debian, cron

I have a strange problem. Using Debian 6 and crontab -e (as root),the following cronjob **works just fine**:

```
 */5 * * * * bin/sh /root/backup
```

but it **does not work** if I set it to run at a specific time:

```
 00 12 * * * bin/sh /root/backup
```

Unfortunately, there is no error at all in the logfiles.

```
 date
```

shows the correct time and timezone.

I have also changed UTC to "no" instead of "yes" in /etc/default/rcS, but that did not help.

I am totally clueless what the reason might be and hope that you may have a solution for me!

Comment: You had the crontab saved by 12:00 on your timezone? /var/log/cron didn't show any errors at all? Or did it show that the task had been run?

Comment: Yes and yes and no.

Comment: Instead of  00 12 * * * bin/sh /root/backup can you try:
0 12 * * * bin/sh /root/backup (or a time very shortly, just a single digit rather than 2)

Comment: Thank you - I tried this before. Unfortunately with no success. Cron can really be a beast sometimes... :/

Comment: Hrm ok, put this script in /etc/cron.d/  does it run then? or do you have any system crons setup? In /etc/cron.d/daily etc? do these run/log?

Comment: Again, thank you for your efforts. Yes. It works if I put it in /etc/cron.d/daily but not in /etc/cron.d/.

Comment: What's in the head of the script?

Comment: #!/bin/bash - If that is what you meant...

Comment: What do you see if you capture the output yourself `00 12 * * * bin/sh /root/backup &>/tmp/logfile`

Comment: Actually, simplify the job: `00 12 * * * bin/sh date > /tmp/logfile`.  See if it's a cron issue or something weird with the script.

Comment: Well, well... :-( I have tried EVERYTHING. Thank you all for your appreciated help. Unfortunately, it did not work out. I have wiped the server and installed CentOS instead. Cron works fine now and as Debian is not really necessary on that server, I will simply stick with CentOS. Again, thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

As has already been mentioned, make sure there is an empty line at the end of the file. I would also not use `bin/sh` but use the absolute path (`/bin/sh`).

What could be the issue (which if there is no error could be considered a bug) is the fact that you're specifying `00` rather than `0`. The specification for time (taken from the man page) is:

```
The time and date fields are:

          field          allowed values
          -----          --------------
          minute         0-59
          hour           0-23
          day of month   1-31
          month          1-12 (or names, see below)
          day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
```

Note that there they are specifying a single digit `0`.

Comment: Well, well... :-( I have tried EVERYTHING. Thank you all for your appreciated help. Unfortunately, it did not work out. I have wiped the server and installed CentOS instead. Cron works fine now and as Debian is not really necessary on that server, I will simply stick with CentOS. Again, thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the line with the specific date is not the last line in your crontab. Vixie cron still had a bug about all crontab lines needing a linefeed to work properly last time I checked.

Perhaps a comment at the end would suffice.

Comment: Thank you - I have double checked this. There is an empty line at the end of the crontab... Still it does not work. :-/

Comment: Judging by all the comments above, I'd be thinking about running strace on the crond process and see what it's doing at the time point where it's supposed to kick off.

Comment: Well, well... :-( I have tried EVERYTHING. Thank you all for your appreciated help. Unfortunately, it did not work out. I have wiped the server and installed CentOS instead. Cron works fine now and as Debian is not really necessary on that server, I will simply stick with CentOS. Again, thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the user portion of the cron job.

```
0 12 * * * root /bin/sh /root/backup
```

Comment: `crontab -e` edit's the users crontab file which doesn't require a username to be specified.

Comment: @Alex: I think hasan may be right. I duplicated same behavior with my Dev box.

Comment: If you do crontab -e as root you don't need the user part. This is how all our crons are at work.

Comment: Well, well... :-( I have tried EVERYTHING. Thank you all for your appreciated help. Unfortunately, it did not work out. I have wiped the server and installed CentOS instead. Cron works fine now and as Debian is not really necessary on that server, I will simply stick with CentOS. Again, thank you all!